# Microsoft Word conditional formatting to change color of cell based on value

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to add conditional formatting to a Word table so that if I enter a value of 1 the cell highlights green, if I enter a value more than 1 it highlights red. I would like this to be done automatically when typing values into a cell.

Example:
[image: Example Excel Table]

I tried to use if expressions as explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-if-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) but I don't know what to put as 'expression1' so that it takes the value of the current cell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered inserting an Excel object rather than a table? You would have all of the same functionality of an Excel sheet in the Word document. Conditional Formatting would be simplest, especially if you wanted to manipulate the data later.

If you're using Office 2016, just click Inset, Object (in the Text group), and choose Microsoft Excel Worksheet.

Comment: I have, it made editing the document very slow. I would prefer to do it directly in Word if possible.

Comment: Would you be open to using a macro that you run? If so, I found a link.